# Most efficent way to play multiple sound files at once?

Tags: c#, forms

Im making a self playing piano where each button is a .wav file note and I want to know the most efficent way to play more of these files at once when needed.
I currently have something like this when encountering the need to play two sounds:

```
                    var p1 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
                    p1.Open(new System.Uri(sound1.wav));
                    p1.Play();
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
                    p2.Open(new System.Uri(sound2.wav));
                    p2.Play();
```

However it does have occasional lag or stutter so is there any better way of doing this?

P.S.
I used the Thread.Sleep because I found it sounds better in the current setup with a small break in it, also looking for a better alternative to Thread.Sleep for making pauses between sounds

Comment: What would be a better way of making timed pauses between sounds?